# How to access Razor Page object in TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am writing a taghelper for ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages applications. In my TagHelper I would like to access the Razor Page object (in purpose to set Layout = null conditionally)

I do know the

```
[HtmlAttributeNotBound]
[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

facility, but the Page is not seems to accessible via ViewContext.

**Question**

Do I have to pass the Page itself explicitly via a TagHelper property, or is there any more convenient way, not to force the user of my TagHelper repeatedly add this extra attribute?

Comment: Can you describe your requirements in detail, or provide us with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewContext.ViewData.Model
```

This returns an object, just cast it to the type you want to access its properties.